# Business logic in RIA service

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I am writing a RIA service. I need to decide where to put the business logic. 
I see two possibilities

1. Use the CRUD methods being called by submitchanges and put the business logic there. The main problem is that in some cases I will need to do more effort to detect what has changed in my object as I don't really know which field changed in my object. The methods themself are expected to become big as needing to deal with multiple entity changes.
2. Give the client specific invoke/named update methods for some of the update ops. These will be called by the UI when doing specific data model change and therefore the effort on the server side will be smaller (will know better the operation being done) and maybe the complication of the server methods will be reduced..

Amit

Answer (score 0):

The second approach makes more sence to me. Client is used only as a terminal to store and show data but there is no contraindications to invoke different server functions as long as you can keep your data consistent. Huge perk is simplicity, ive been tought the easier the better.